Can we use "day and night time" instead of "day and night"?
Can we use day and night time instead of day and night in a sentence? Is the use or addition of the word time with the phrase day and night correct or not?

Adding Time brings the two into a comparison of time periods. Saying just Day and Night compares the non-time/instantaneous status; light and dark, up and down, inside and outside.  This is the purpose of the usage, not a time period.

The term nighttime or night-time should not be capitalised, it is not a proper noun.

Maria-Lou A, question edited. Is it understandable now?

Some sample possible sentences would be helpful. There is a difference between "They are as different as day and night" and "The machines run day and night".

There's a famous conversation in the Sherlock Holmes story "Silver Blaze":   Gregory (Scotland Yard detective): Is there any other point to which you would wish to draw my attention?
Holmes: To the curious incident of the dog in the night-time.  Gregory: The dog did nothing in the night-time.
Holmes: That was the curious incident. - Or are you referring to the use of day and night together?

Retracted downvote :) But the question is still unclear. Do mean can we add "time" as in "It is daytime" (one word) or do you mean adding "time" to either day and night For example: "I work day time and night time”? The usual, and most idiomatic,  expression is: "I work day and night"

@ermanen. Yes the question is crystal clear now.

Much depends on what sentence you want to write.  Using "day and night time" will not work in most instances.

Day and night time is not an idiomatic or set phrase (unlike day and night), but it can be used appropriately in certain contexts, particularly in technical ones.
Here is a relevant usage I've found:

The English word day can be used to refer to the time of daylight or to the unit of time that encompasses both day and night time.
Space and Time in Languages and Cultures Language, culture, and cognition


It is unusual to write “day time" and "night time" as two individual words. See Google Ngram charts for comparison.
First American English,

and British English

As can be seen from the above charts, the one word spelling variant is by far the most commonly used. Furthermore, many of the results of the two-word spelling variant are in reality hyphenated e.g. the night-time equivalent sound level, and several are false positives such as a new 120-day time period.
Can the OP write "day and night time"? There is no rule that I know of that forbids this usage, but I would strongly advise using the one-word spelling variant: "nighttime"
Finally, the Ngram chart below shows the popularity of the following expressions in the English corpus: a) day and night time, b) day and nighttime, c) day and night,  and d) night and day between 1930 and 2022. The instances of the last two variants (c and d) clearly demonstrate their superiority compared the the first two (a and b) which in comparison are flatlines.


It would be odd to use "day and nighttime", however.  "Day and night" is sensible, as is "Daytime and nighttime" (and the two are essentially equivalent, though the former is more common).  "Day and night time" is more ambiguous whether the "time" is intended to be tightly bound to "night" alone or to apply to both, but in any case is redundant, though readily understood.

@Miral I don't disagree but maybe you should address your comment to the OP or ermanen?

I addressed it to you because you were the one who suggested replacing "night time" with "nighttime".
